# Converting from hexadecimal string to byte array in C

Tags: c, hex, arrays

I am sending byte arrays between a TCP socket server & client in C. The information that I am sending is a series of integers.

I have it working, but because I am not too conversant with C, I was wondering if anyone could suggest a better solution, or at least to look and tell me that I'm not being too crazy or using outdated code with what I'm doing.

First, I generate a random decimal value, let's say "350". I need to transmit this over the socket connection as a hex byte array. It is decoded back to its decimal value at the other end.

So far, I convert it to hex this way:

```
unsigned char hexstr[4];
sprintf(hexstr, "%02X", numToConvert);  \\ where numToConvert is a decimal integer value like 350
```

At this point, I have a string in hexstr that's something like "15E" (again, using the hex value of 350 for an example).

Now, I need to store this in a byte array so that it looks something like: myArray = {0X00, 0X00, 0X01, 0X5E};

Obviously I can't just write: myArray = {0X00, 0X00, 0X01, 0X5E} because the values will be different every time, since a new random number is generated every time.

Currently, I do it like this (pseudocode because the string manipulation part is irrelevant but long):

```
lastTwoChars = getLastTwoCharsFromString(hexstr); // so lastTwoChars would now contain "5E"
```

Then (actual code):

```
sscanf(lastTwoChars, "%0X", &res); // now the variable res contains the byte representation of lastTwoChars, is my understanding
```

Then finally:

```
myArray[3] = res;
```

Then, I take the next two rightmost chars from hexstr (again, using the sample value of "15E", this would be "01" -- if there's only 1 more character, as in this case "1" was the only character left after taking out "5E" from "15E", I add 0s to the left to pad) and convert that the same way using sscanf, then insert into myArray[2]. Repeat for myArray[1] and myArray[0].

Then I send the array using write().

So, after hours of plugging away at it, this all does work... but because I don't use C very much, I have a nagging suspicion that there's something I am missing in all this. Can anyone comment if what I'm doing seems OK, or there's something obvious I'm using improperly or neglecting to use?

Comment: Are you attempting to encode the number as a printable ASCII string, or just transmit the number as four bytes, binary encoded?

Comment: Your code looks correct, but it's a bit hard to tell, because you don't show much code. Instead of `sscanf` you can use the somewhat simpler `strtol` and instead of `sprintf` you can use `itoa`.

Comment: I'm just trying to convert and transmit the number to an array of bytes with a length of 4. In C#, I would do this with:

    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number); -- where number is a uint.


That's how I did do it in C#, and now I'm redoing it in C.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(){
    unsigned num = 0x15E;//num=350
    int i, size = sizeof(unsigned);
    unsigned char myArray[size];
    for(i=size-1;i>=0;--i, num>>=CHAR_BIT){
        myArray[i] = num & 0xFF;
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        printf("0X%02hhX ", myArray[i]);//0X02X
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "unsigned num"? Can you do that? Also, to be clear, 0X15E isn't meant to be a hardcoded value.

Comment: @mrrrow `unsigned num` is just fine.

Comment: @mrrrow ,I can be omitted `int`.

Comment: Can you do it like this, or does it need the 0x?: unsigned num = 15E

Comment: @mrrrow It(`0x`) is required to hexadecimal constant.

Comment: OK, so I would do something like "sprintf(hexstr, "0X%02hhX", numToConvert)" to get hexstr to hold the value of "0X15E", but this is the part that I don't get. What would I use to get 0X15E (to plug into unsigned num), not "0X15E"? Thanks so much for your help thus far.

Comment: @mrrrow you get `myArray = {0X00, 0X00, 0X01, 0X5E} `

Comment: Pardon, I don't understand your answer. I get myArray from where?

Comment: My question is, how do you get from an unsigned int 350 to "unsigned num = 0x15E;"? Other than the way I explained I did it...

Comment: @mrrrow, from the `num` , yes, you can write `unsigned int num = 350;`

Comment: @mrrow you need to stop thinking about `sprintf`. That function is for converting an integer to a human-readable string. What you are trying to do is pack an integer into some memory. `sprintf` is not a part of that process.

Comment: I've tried implementing this solution, and it seems to work fine, inso far as it prints out the right conversions to the screen. However, now when I try to send the data using "write(sock, myArray, 4)" (which worked before) I now get a bunch of little square boxes on the screen with 0s and 1s in them, and no data is transmitted. Any thoughts?

Comment: Matt: I do need to convert to a human readable string also, as part of the criteria is printing out the hex digits to the screen.

Comment: I got it working, thank you. Now to study exactly how this works... Thanks so much!

Comment: One more question -- you used unsigned int, while user3386109 below used uint32_t and stressed the importance of not using generic types. What do you think of that?

Comment: @mrrrow ; Size of the basic such as int in C, so not decided for sure, So must be as follows : `size = sizeof(unsigned); unsigned char myArray[size];` . But better to use the `uint32_t` is clearly defined size you're dealing with now if're clearly decided to it is better.

Comment: @mrrrow As a general, you use to `uint32_t` is good if you need `assert(sizeof (unsinged) == 4) `.

Comment: Thank you. I studied your code and understand it now. I learned a lot!

Answer (score 1):

On the transmit side, convert a 32-bit number to a four byte array with this code

```
void ConvertValueToArray( uint32_t value, uint8_t array[] )
{
    int i;

    for ( i = 3; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        array[i] = value & 0xff;
        value >>= 8;
    }
}
```

On the receive side, convert the byte array back into a number with this code

```
uint32_t ConvertArrayToValue( uint8_t array[] )
{
    int i;
    uint32_t value = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        value <<= 8;
        value |= array[i];
    }

    return( value );
}
```

Note that it's important **not** to use generic types like `int` when writing this kind of code, since an `int` can be different sizes on different systems.  The fixed-sized types are defined in `<stdint.h>`.

Here's a simple test that demonstrates the conversions (without actually sending the byte arrays over the network).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main( void )
{
    uint32_t input, output;
    uint8_t byte_array[4];

    input = 350;
    ConvertValueToArray( input, byte_array );

    output = ConvertArrayToValue( byte_array );
    printf( "%u\n", output );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot as well. 
I'm curious, in BluePixy's solution, they used code pretty similar to yours, but a char array versus an int array. Why did you choose to go with an int array for your solution? (I ended up going with the char array because it turned out easier for me to print the contents of the char array than the int array, but that's probably only because I don't know how to do it with the int array.)

Comment: In the C programming language, the built-in types (`int`, `char`, etc) do not have well defined sizes.  For example, an `int` could be 16, 32, or 64 bits, depending on the compiler and system hardware.  Using the types in `<stdint.h>` allows you to specify the exact size of a variable.  For example, `uint8_t` is an unsigned value with 8 bits.  On almost all systems, `uint8_t` is the same as `unsigned char`, and so you can use an `uint8_t` anywhere you would use an `unsigned char`.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind: Do you think it's always better to use uint32_t for example instead of an int? Say you're doing a for loop that goes from i=0; i < 10. Do you still think it's useful to use "uint32_t i;" to declare i, instead of just "int i" which is more readable? I.e. should I use these types indiscriminately? Or do you mean only that it's useful to use the stdint.h types in certain situations, such as when doing things like byte conversions where you don't know what might be in the byte?

Comment: @mrrrow In general, I prefer to avoid the `stdint.h` types because the type names are, shall we say, messy.  So when writing a simple `for` loop, I'll declare `i` as `int`.  But there are situations where you need to guarantee that a variable is a certain size. A few examples that come to mind, 1) sending data across a network, 2) graphics routines, e.g. writing directly to a pixel buffer, 3) direct hardware access, e.g. writing device drivers.  In all of these, the size of the variable and byte ordering are important, and need to be controlled. That's where the `stdint.h` types come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is 4-byte aligned (and even if it isn't on machines that support unaligned access), you can use the `htonl` function to convert a 32-bit integer from host to network byte order and store the whole thing at once:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h> // or <netinet/in.h>

...

    *(uint32_t*)myArray = htonl(num);
```

Comment: You can avoid the alignment issue by doing `uint32_t temp = htonl(num); memcpy(myArray, &temp, 4);`

Comment: I thought htonl was just for flipping the order of bytes in a long, as  necessary for little endian/big endian. Are you saying it can also be used to convert a 32-bit integer to byte array? Is there any documentation you can point me to about it? Thank you.

Comment: Memory is just a big array of bytes, so a 32-bit integer, when stored in memory, is an array of 4 bytes.  You just need to get the bytes in the correct (network) order.

Comment: You are saying I can use this instead of the solutions involving bit shifting suggested above?

Comment: Yes, try it out and see for yourself!

Comment: Aside from less lines of code, would you say there is an advantage to doing it this way versus the solutions given above? Or disadvantages?

Comment: This solution has the best performance.  The function name is short for "host to network long" for a reason.  It is used to convert a 32-bit value from host format to a format that can be sent through the network.